# How do I use series int correctly in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I want to use a result of a function for an other function to find Lows and Highs in the chart.

For the ta.highestbars, the script doesn´t work anyway. So it means the script works but in the chart itself it doesn´t work and I get a warning about a mistake that the function ta.highestbars have a wrong insert.

Maybe somebody is able to explain me how I can use a series int variable for ta.highestbars within it works.

Thank you very much in advance.

Here is my script:

```
// This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at        https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Nikbaumi

//@version=5
indicator(title="Strategie 1.0 ohne arrays", overlay=true)
import TradingView/ta/7

// Anzahl der Balken die betrachtet werden
N_BARS = input (200)

// Aufwärtstrend (LONG)
// Suche nach dem tiefsten Low
LONG_Lowest_bar_index = ta.lowestbars(low, N_BARS)
LONG_Lowest_bar_price = ta.lowest(low, N_BARS)

// Label für das tiefste Low
LONG_Lowest_bar_point = chart.point.from_time(LONG_Lowest_bar_index, LONG_Lowest_bar_price)
var LONG_Lowest_bar_label = label.new(LONG_Lowest_bar_point, text = 'Low', color = color.gray, textcolor     = color.lime, size = size.normal, style = label.style_label_up)
label.set_x(LONG_Lowest_bar_label, bar_index + LONG_Lowest_bar_index)
label.set_y(LONG_Lowest_bar_label, LONG_Lowest_bar_price)

// Plot des tiefsten Lows
plot(LONG_Lowest_bar_index, title = 'LBI', color = color.green)
plot(LONG_Lowest_bar_price, title = 'LBP', color = color.blue)

// Suche nach High nach dem tiefsten Low
LONG_N_BARS_Higher = - LONG_Lowest_bar_index
// LONG_N_BARS_Higher = 100

LONG_Higher_bar_index = ta.highestbars(high, LONG_N_BARS_Higher)
LONG_Higher_bar_price = ta.highest(high, LONG_N_BARS_Higher)

// Label für das High nach dem tiefsten Low
LONG_Higher_bar_point = chart.point.from_time(LONG_Higher_bar_index, LONG_Higher_bar_price)
var LONG_Higher_bar_label = label.new(LONG_Higher_bar_point, text = 'HH', color = color.gray, textcolor     = color.lime, size = size.normal, style = label.style_label_down)
label.set_x(LONG_Higher_bar_label, bar_index + LONG_Higher_bar_index)
label.set_y(LONG_Higher_bar_label, LONG_Higher_bar_price)

// Plot des High nach dem tiefsten Lows
plot(LONG_Higher_bar_index, title = 'HBI', color = color.green)
plot(LONG_Higher_bar_price, title = 'HBP', color = color.blue)
```